# How to change pie chart segment colors in plotly with r RColorBrewer custom colors

Tags: r, colors, plotly, pie-chart

I'm new to coding, and this is my first time asking a question here so forgive me if this doesn't follow the correct format for questions. 
I'm trying to change pie chart colors in plotly with R from the default to `RColorBrewer`, or, alternatively any custom colors. I've tried all the suggestions I've found on here so far, but none have been successful. 
My current code is below which defaults to a blue / orange color combination:

```
labels = c('Australia','Elsewhere')
values = c(199656, 82883)

fig <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=labels, values=values,
               textinfo='label+percent',
               insidetextorientation='radial') 

theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.0))

fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Logan Population by Birthplace 2016")

fig
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set custom colors via the `colors` attribute of `marker`. For more on styling pie charts see [here](https://plotly.com/r/pie-charts/):

```r
library(plotly)

labels <- c("Australia", "Elsewhere")
values <- c(199656, 82883)

cols <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Blues")[seq_along(labels)]

plot_ly(
  type = "pie",
  labels = labels,
  values = values,
  marker = list(colors = cols),
  textinfo = "label+percent",
  insidetextorientation = "radial"
) %>%
  layout(title = "Logan Population by Birthplace 2016")
```

[image]